# TFS - How do I loop through a LinkCollection object?

Tags: c#, api, tfs

I have this nested `LinkCollection` object which has `Results` which is a list but I am unable to iterate through this list because it sees this object as a single object (I am 100% sure there is a list embedded in there).

This `LinkCollection` class is nested within this structure `Changeset[].WorkItem[].Links` - I am able to loop through the upper classes but have a problem when I get to the `Links` object.

This is my code

```
    public Changeset CheckForDuplicateChangeset(Changeset cs)
    {
        foreach (WorkItem wi in cs.WorkItems)
        {
            foreach (var link in wi.Links)
            {
                //Here I cannot access the link properties 
                //from the "link" within my foreach loop
            }
        }

        //This this the property I want to access within the Links object
        if (cs.WorkItems[0].Links[0].BaseType == BaseLinkType.ExternalLink)
        {                
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The fully qualified name for the `Changeset` class is `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Changeset`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled until I found the answer. Basically I need to specify  the type of the object within the `LinkCollection`. The type is Link. So this is how my nested loop looks now.

```
foreach (WorkItem wi in cs.WorkItems)
{
    foreach (Link link in wi.Links)
    {  
        if (link.BaseType == BaseLinkType.ExternalLink)
        {
            //Implement my logic
        }
    }
}
```